# Remove a file that was previously added from Shared With Me to My Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

Google Drive has a cool feature: one can add a file or folder from Shared With Me to My Drive.

[image]

Then I can delete this file from My Drive in the same manner (note that if I delete shared file in web version it won't go to Trash)

[image]

However, I am getting 403 Forbidden error while trying to delete this file using Google Drive API (because of insufficient permissions due to that I am not owner of this file). So, as one can see, this is not a simple Delete request. How can I implement this functionality?

Comment: Just a guess. "Delete from My Drive" isn't deleting the file, simply removing My Drive as a parent. Whereas in the Drive API, delete really tries to erase the file. Try using Try It or http://www.clevernote.co/app/drivecrud.html to look at the file's meta data before and after Delete From My Drive, to see what is being changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to My Drive changes the parents collection for the item in question. To change this, you will want to unparent the item rather than delete.

Use the about.get call to retrieve the My Drive ID, then remove that ID from the list of parents in the file resource for the file/folder. Update the file with the new list of parents.

Comment: I tried to implement your solution but couldn't delete the file. Can you lead me, what I am doing wrong. Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36015627/delete-a-file-completely-from-shared-with-me-folder

Answer (score 3):

A late answer, but I ran into this issue too. This happens because the file isn't actually copied, it's the same instance. If you remove it from My Drive, it will be removed from the Shared Drive too. And you may lack permission to remove it from the Shared Drive.

If you want to just remove it from My Drive: click on the file. In the right panel, under Details, there is a list of locations. At least the Shared Drive and My Drive is listed there. Click the X to remove it from My Drive, and it will disappear there while preserved on the Shared Drive.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found. After removing the parent of an item shared with me, do a `sharedWithMe` search still return the item, even though the item's parent list is empty.

Here is the code:

```
string sItemId = (this is the Id of the item shared with me);
string sParentId = driveService.About.Get().Execute().RootFolderId;
driveService.Parents.Delete(sItemId, sParentId).Execute();
var parentList = m_driveService.Parents.List(sItemId).Execute();
```

At this point `parentList.Items.Count` is `0`.

Now when I search `sharedWithMe` the item is in the return list.

Comment: Looks like sharedWithMe items don't have parents. So Alexander's question still has no answer!