# Delete a file completely from shared with me folder

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am trying to delete a file which is shared with me using Google Drive API but since I'm not the owner of the file I'm getting a permission error. I looked the on the web and find this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29084127/remove-a-file-that-was-previously-added-from-shared-with-me-to-my-drive/29104560#29104560). I implemented the solution as below:

```
About about = service.about().get().execute();
String rootId = about.getRootFolderId();
service.parents().delete(fileId, rootId).execute();
```

However, I cannot delete the file with this code. It doesn't give any error but I can still see the file in my google drive.

PS: I checked the `fileId` parameter and it's referencing to the correct file.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't Know java so couldn't provide any code sample.

So In Google Drive API V3 you can no longer get the root folder Id by `getRootFolderId` method using About Resource.

Instead you need to use `file.get` method, use `root` (instead of your file Id) as the `fileId` and request additional field `id` (passing `?fields=id`) to get the rootFolderId.

In the Drive API V3 they have stopped returning full resource by default. So be careful if you use any code related to V2.

Check out the [Fields](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration#fields) Section in google drives api official migration document.

Hope this helps.

Thanks